# Event Grid Trigger Azure Function: How to access metadata(user defined key, value pair) of deleted blobs?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-webjobssdk, azure-eventgrid

How to get metadata of deleted blob in Event Grid Trigger Azure Function? Below is a sample C# code -

```
[FunctionName("EventGridTriggerFunction")] 
public static void Run([EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent, ILogger log) 
{ log.LogInformation(eventGridEvent.Data.ToString());
}
```

Can I get from EventGridEvent --> data object property? Is there any way to set custom event schema with blob's metadata?

Referring link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage

```
[{
  "topic": "/subscriptions/{subscription-id}/resourceGroups/Storage/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/my-storage-account",
  "subject": "/blobServices/default/containers/test-container/blobs/new-file.txt",
  "eventType": "Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated",
  "eventTime": "2017-06-26T18:41:00.9584103Z",
  "id": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e069631",
  "***data***": {
    "api": "PutBlockList",
    "clientRequestId": "6d79dbfb-0e37-4fc4-981f-442c9ca65760",
    "requestId": "831e1650-001e-001b-66ab-eeb76e000000",
    "eTag": "\"0x8D4BCC2E4835CD0\"",
    "contentType": "text/plain",
    "contentLength": 524288,
    "blobType": "BlockBlob",
    "url": "https://my-storage-account.blob.core.windows.net/testcontainer/new-file.txt",
    "sequencer": "00000000000004420000000000028963",
    "storageDiagnostics": {
      "batchId": "b68529f3-68cd-4744-baa4-3c0498ec19f0"
    }
  },
  "dataVersion": "",
  "metadataVersion": "1"
}]
```

Comment: the user metadata of the blob file are not a part of the data object in the event message. You can get them only when the blob file exists.

Comment: Thank you, Roman! Yes, you are right. Is there any alternate way? Basically I wanted to show the entire audit trail info. (uploaded/deleted/modified) of blob/file. Through REST Api (PUT BLOB) call I am setting blob's metadata along with user details. Will really appreciate if you help me.

Comment: There is no elegant workaround for your solution. However, **turn-on soft delete for blobs** option will enable to get the blob metadata in the eventgridtrigger subscriber after calling the *undelete blob* request.

Comment: ok but _undelete blob_ request will restore content as well. Can I achieve by creating a custom event data/schema? If yes then how?

Comment: Once again, you can not customized a data object in the event message emitted by blob storage account. Your subscriber will call undelete blob, then get the blob metadata, checking metadata, setting the metadata and deleting again this blob. That's the non-elegant way how to retrieve the metadata from the soft deleted blob. It will be nice to get the metadata from the invisible blob which has been marked as deleted, but currently this feature is not supported.

Comment: Thank you Roman for the detailed information

Comment: @RomanKiss For this question, your answer is really good, could you send your answer below? This can help more forum users.

Comment: @JasonPan, I have included a working sample for EventGridTrigger function to get the metadata from the soft deleted blob.

Comment: @RomanKiss, Unfortunately we can't set metadata while deleting blob using REST API Delete call. I don't know why there are limitations. I wanted to set who is deleted the blob and catch it into Event Grid trigger function(subscriber). Is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

There is no elegant workaround for your solution. However, **turn-on soft delete for blobs** option in the storage account will enable to get the blob metadata in the *EventGridTrigger* subscriber after calling the undelete blob request.

The following code snippet shows this implementation example:

run.csx:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"

using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
using System.Linq;


public static async Task Run(JObject eventGridEvent, CloudBlockBlob blob, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"{eventGridEvent}");

    if (eventGridEvent["data"]["contentType"].Value<string>() != "abcd" && eventGridEvent["data"]["api"].Value<string>() == "DeleteBlob")
    {
        await blob.UndeleteAsync();
        await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();           
    
        log.LogInformation($"\nMetadata: {string.Join(" | ", blob.Metadata.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}");
    
        // ...
    
        blob.Properties.ContentType = "abcd";
        await blob.SetPropertiesAsync();
        await blob.DeleteAsync();
    }
    else if (eventGridEvent["data"]["contentType"].Value<string>() != "abcd")
    {
        await blob.FetchAttributesAsync();           
    
        log.LogInformation($"\nMetadata: {string.Join(" | ", blob.Metadata.Select(i => $"{i.Key}={i.Value}"))}");

    }

    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "eventGridEvent",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "name": "blob",
      "path": "{data.url}",
      "connection": "rk2018ebstg_STORAGE",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

Note, that the data object in the event message emitted by storage account included only two properties of the blob file such as *contentType* and *contentLength*.

The above implementation used for avoiding the cycling of the *DeleteBlob* by subscriber the blob property contentType with unexpected value, for instance: *abcd*.

It will be nice, if the soft deleted blob allows to retrieve its properties and/or metadata. I have wrote the feedback for this option [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/41366218-allow-to-get-a-metadata-from-the-soft-deleted-blob).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Roman Kiss for this.  This workaround is so helpful to get out of the infinite Delete Blob loop when undeleting/re-deleting in the event handler.

To add to the solution, if you are using the Azure python sdk, here's how you set the content type when deleting a blob as it's not completely obvious in the api:

```
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(
      conn_str=os.getenv('AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING'))
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(
      container = container_name,
      blob = blob_name)
blob_client.set_http_headers(content_settings=ContentSettings(content_type=CUSTOM_CONTENT_TYPE))
blob_client.delete_blob()
```